# Download an internet resource in Python and save it on my desired location

Tags: python, urllib2

I am new to Python and I am using `urllib2` to download files over the internet. 
I am using this code

```
import urllib2
response = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.example.com/myfile.zip')
...
```

This code actually save the zip file on my temp folder, I don't want it to be like that, I want to save it on my desired location. Is it possible?

Comment: Try using 'os' module to change your directory. 
os.chdir('/path/desired/')

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `urllib.urlretrieve` function, to download the distant file to your local filesystem.

```
>>> import urllib
>>> urllib.urlretrieve('http://www.example.com/myfile.zip', 'path/to/download/dir/myfile.zip')
```

See the `urllib.urlretrieve` [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlretrieve) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use something like this :

```
f = open("path_to_your_file_to_save", 'w')
f.write(urllib.urlopen(url).read())
f.close()
```

Where `path_to_your_file_to_save` equals [path_where_save] + [filename.ext]