# How to save to specific path AND prented to be a browser at once

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib2, urllib

[urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13303449/urllib2-httperror-http-error-403-forbidden)
I've seen this, but it doesn't directly answer me.
I want to download and save to certain directory so I am using

```
urllib.request.urlretrieve('url','path')
```

However that certain download is forbid me so I need to use urllib2 which doesn't seem to be able to save to certain directory see here: [Download an internet resource in Python and save it on my desired location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16479365/download-an-internet-resource-in-python-and-save-it-on-my-desired-location)

Is there any way I can download file to a specific directory and spoof a browser all at once?

Comment: I'll look into the new "powerful" requests module.